# How do I write foreach loop?

Tags: java, foreach

I want to write foreach like this:

```
for (Object object1 : list1 , Object object2 : list2)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Your compiler will tell you what is legal or not. What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps nesting the loops might help. If your code causes error messages, it would be wise to post them with your question and not make us guess.

Comment: you could go to the java doc to find out more about foreach

Comment: I want to read from both of list row by row concurrently

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21074363/948909 (the first code)

Comment: @user35443 your code does not work when the length of two list not equal

Comment: "Note that if one of the collections is smaller than other, additional elements in bigger collection won't be processed."  - There's no way to predict the values that should be used when an end of only one collection is reached (from my side, you may know what to use). The code will work when the length of two lists is not equal, although only until there are two elements available for processing.

Comment: @user35443 but my code will work even the size of two list are not equal - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21074510/2034653

Answer (score 5):

Write it as nested loop to iterate over all element combinations

```
for (Object object1 : list1){
   for (Object object2 : list2){
      ...
   }
}
```

or in one iteration with `do...while`, this is equal to code above.

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
do {
    Object object1 = a.get(i)
    Object object2 = b.get(j)
    ...
    if (i == a.size() - 1) j++;
} while (i < a.size() && j < b.size());
```

You can also merge both lists and then iterate all elements one by one

```
// Add items to the other list - BEWARE - list1's contens will change
list1.addAll(list2);

for (Object object : list1) {
   ...
}
```

Safe way with Guava

```
Iterable<Object> combined = Iterables.unmodifiableIterable(
        Iterables.concat(list1, list2));
for (Object object : combined) {
    System.out.println(object);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to do.

If you want to iterate 0th to Nth item in both collections being able to work with elements of both in one loop body, you can write something like this:

```
for(int i = 0;i < list1.size() && i < list2.size();i++) {
    Object object1 = list1.get(i);
    Object object2 = list2.get(i);

    /* your code */
    ...
}
```

Note that if one of the collections is smaller than other, additional elements in bigger collection won't be processed.

If you want to iterate list1 and then list2, you can simply create a new one containing previous two:

```
List<Object> n = new ArrayList<Object>(list1);
n.addAll(list2)
for(Object o : n) {
    /* your code */
    ...
}
```

Or finally, if you want to iterate list of lists, you can

```
for(List<Object> il : (List<List<Object>>)list1) {
    for(Object o : il) {
        /* code for each object in child list */
        ...
    }

    /* code for each child list in parent */
    ...
}
```

Comment: if the size of two list be different

Comment: In that case it works, see the explanation under OP´s question.

Answer (score 0):

In a single foreach statement you are not allowed to iterate through two collections at the same time. If you want to use only one foreach, you must merge the collections first.

You could do it like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         String s1 = "string 1";
         String s2 = "string 2";
         String s3 = "string 3";
         String s4 = "string 4";

         List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

         List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

         list1.add(s1);
         list1.add(s2);

         list2.add(s3);
         list2.add(s4);

         List<String> merged = new ArrayList<String>();
         merged.addAll(list1);
         merged.addAll(list2);

         for(String s : merged)
         {
            System.out.println(s);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to write like that but you can use this code instead

i hope if it will help you

```
    String []one={"hello","thanks"};
    int[]two={1,2,3};
    String item;
    int flag;
    for(int i=0;i<one.length+two.length;i++){
        if(i<one.length){
            item=one[i];
            System.out.println(item);
        }
        if(i<two.length){
            flag=two[i];
        System.out.println(flag);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense, as he could equally write two loops with two different ranges of ´i´ (where one would be (possibly equal) subset of the other), without having any difference.

Comment: it work and it is not expensive but what are you suggesting is expensive

Comment: Expensive? Are you buying something?

Comment: it mean that it will take more time to exec